# Mobile Game Auth Token Stolen

Tags: authentication

Basically someone sniffed my packets and stole my auth token/cookie for a mobile game I have played on for a year and spent thousands on (crazy I know) and now they are controlling my account through their laptop and are threatening to delete all my progress.

I have tried changing my email address and password many, many times and it does generate new tokens but the old token still works also. I have spent weeks researching and trying to figure out how I can get them off my account.

I have emailed the devs many times, but they are clueless and unhelpful, so this is my last resort, please help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The game is Elemental Kingdoms, it's on Android and iOS and is made by iFree Studios in Hong Kong and licensed by Perfect World/Fedeen in the West. I was just wondering if there was a way to force the system to flush the old tokens. I know from research, that with Google tokens, if you change your password 25 times, it can only hold 25 tokens, so it starts flushing them. Is there any other ways to get rid of tokens?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the situation you describe appears unsolvable. You need to invalidate the token, but the only ones that can do so are the game developers.

Possibly you can persuade them of your identity, and after creating a new account have them transfer everything from the old to the new. The unknown crackers would then find themselves with an empty, lifeless husk of your old account.

Other approaches could involve trying to locate the unknown parties that have your token. If they're *threatening* I guess they're *communicating* somehow. (Just in case -- I'm **not** advocating recoursing to counter-threats. Things might end badly, or deteriorate anyhow. But knowing enough about the responsible parties might offer leverage [e.g. "they" is a skript kid with reasonable parents], or even *be* leverage by itself. It is difficult to erase the gaming account of someone who knows who you are and where you live, and *might* recourse to [rubber-hose cryptanalysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-hose_cryptanalysis)).

You could also try and involve the police in this: at least in my country, *any* identifying access token, be it a stainless steel key, a code on a slip of paper, or a password, is considered *my* property and e.g. copying it with pencil and paper (with intention to use it to access *my* data) is a criminal offense. The nature of the data - online game, biscuit recipe or online banking account - is irrelevant.

So e.g. agreeing to release a sizeable amount of money or valuable hardware in exchange for a guarantee of the token being destroyed (a silly proposition - as they say, *once you pay Danegeld, you never get rid of the Dane*) would likely result in the culprit or culprits, usually not too experienced in the ways of crime, having you leave the booty somewhere and being intercepted by the police as they attempt recovery.